# chrome tabs event don't work on background js

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

in my permission

```
 "background": {
      "scripts": [ "request.js" ]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "uefa.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "as2"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "content.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
   } ],
   "description": "moving",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "as2",
   "permissions": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "tabs", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "storage", "webNavigation", "\u003Call_urls>", "cookies" ],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.4",

and request.js

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab)
{   
alert("onUpdated"+tab.url);
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
 alert("onActivate"+tab.url);
}); 

chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},function(windows)
{
 windows.forEach(function(window)
 {
  window.tabs.forEach(function(tab)
  { 
    if(tab.url.indexOf("https://www.bet-at-home.com/en/sport/live/") != -1)
    {
      alert("ssdsf::"+tab.id);
    }               
    });
  });
});
```

it is works well!
but problem is if without debug window, it never works.
anybody knows about these bug?

it has tabs permission already, and did not work tabs.remove too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? I ran your code with a blank `popup.html` and the following `manifest.json` and onUpdated worked fine:

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "request.js" ]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "as2"
   },
   "description": "moving",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "as2",
   "permissions": [ "tabs" ],
   "version": "1.4"
}
```